# RSS feed not displaying excerpt text?

Tags: rss, feed

I am attempting to fix my RSS feed and have implemented the following code below in my `functions.php`. How do I go about getting the excerpt text to display in this RSS feed? The following code seems to be working as the featured image is now showing up in my feed (for example at: example.com/feed).

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Customize RSS Feed
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail') . get_the_excerpt($post->ID);
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_
```

Comment: _Seems to be working_? What's the problem then? Also, you're missing some code at the end.

Comment: This part of the code doesn't seem to display the excerpt text in the feed: get_the_excerpt($post->ID)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried but still facing issue can you check please?
TheGoals.us/feed[enter link description here](https://thegoals.us/feed/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/264858)